# Catch block not called in async future flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, firebase-authentication

Why is my catch block not called in this code when there is exception

```
Future registerWithCredentials() async {
if(state.status == RegisterStatus.loading) return;
emit(state.copyWith(status: RegisterStatus.loading));
try{
  await _authRepository.register(email: state.email, password: state.password);
  emit(state.copyWith(status: RegisterStatus.success));
}catch (e) {
  //catch errors
  debugPrint('except: "there is an error"');
  emit(state.copyWith(status: RegisterStatus.error));
 }
}
```

I have also tried like this:

```
try {
await _authRepository.register(email: state.email, password: state.password);
emit(state.copyWith(status: RegisterStatus.success));
 } on FirebaseAuthException catch  (e) {
 debugPrint('except: "there is an error"');
 emit(state.copyWith(status: RegisterStatus.error));
}
```

**Repository -> register**

```
Future<void> register({
required String email,
required String password,
  }) async {
  try {
    await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, 
password: password);
  } catch(_) {
    //the catch here works but I need to send the error to cubit above and 
also send to UI... how to do that
 }
```

}

This what I want to do -> Send the error from repository to cubit to ui and display in widget/ui

Comment: Can you include more about `register`

Comment: Please check question, I have added

Comment: can you try `catch(_) {  throw Exception(("exception")}` on `register` also you can throw `FirebaseAuthException`

Comment: The print statement in the catch block (In register) works well... I can catch the error from the repository (register) but I can't catch it in cubit registerWithCredentials()

Comment: Sorry, don't know, I hope you'll get the answer soon enough.

Comment: What is the exception?  What is the stacktrace?  Are you certain that the exception is thrown from within the `try` block and isn't coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If you catch the exception in the repository, then you have "used" (handled) the exception. If you want to catch the same exception in the bloc, you'll have to rethrow it. So, either re-throw the exception, or remove the try catch in the repository.